# How to update table in Hive 0.13?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, acid

My Hive version is 0.13. I have two tables, `table_1` and `table_2`

`table_1` contains:

```
customer_id | items | price | updated_date
------------+-------+-------+-------------
10          | watch | 1000  | 20170626
11          | bat   | 400   | 20170625
```

`table_2` contains:

```
customer_id | items    | price | updated_date
------------+----------+-------+-------------
10          | computer | 20000 | 20170624
```

I want to update records of `table_2` if `customer_id` already exists in it, if not, it should append to `table_2`.

As Hive 0.13 does not support update, I tried using join, but it fails.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `row_number` or `full join`. This is example using `row_number`:

```
insert overwrite table_1 
select customer_id, items, price, updated_date
from
(
select customer_id, items, price, updated_date,
       row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by new_flag desc) rn
from 
    (
     select customer_id, items, price, updated_date, 0 as new_flag
       from table_1
     union all
     select customer_id, items, price, updated_date, 1 as new_flag
       from table_2
    ) all_data
)s where rn=1;
```

Also see this answer for update using `FULL JOIN`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37744071/2700344