# Guidance in re-writing query using NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

We have a query that runs for different sources, many times every day.
Each time it runs for 40+ minutes and we are trying to see if we can reduce the query execution time

All the query does is tries to add new rows to the existing table ( by comparing on keys )

```
                    SELECT          A.*
                    FROM            
                    ( 
                                       SELECT *
                                       FROM   A 
                    )
                    A
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                                    ( 
                                           SELECT f1, f11
                                           FROM   B 
                                           WHERE  f13 IN  (  SELECT f13 FROM   C) 
                                    ) 
                    B 
                    ON              A.f1 = B.f1
                    AND             nvl(A.f11,'NULL') = nvl(B.f11,'NULL')
                    WHERE           isnull(B.f1) 
                    AND             isnotnull(A.f1)
```

What I am trying to do

```
                    SELECT          A.* .
                    FROM            ( 
                                           SELECT * 
                                           FROM   A 
                                   ) 
                    A
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS  
                                    ( 
                                           SELECT 1
                                           FROM   B  WHERE  f13 IN  (  SELECT f13 FROM   C)
                                           and A.f1 = B.f1 and A.f11 = B.f11

                                    )
```

Will this work to not only generate similar results but also help in reducing the execution time.
A small improvement in query will go a long way as this query runs for 8 times every day.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Afaik `hive` supports `MERGE`

Comment: Check the explain plan, In Hive 1.2 NOT EXISTS generates the same plan as left join + isnull filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hive `NOT EXISTS` will generate the same plan as `left join + isnull filter`.

You can use UNION + `row_number()` for incremental updates like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44755825/2700344, without join, it may work faster