# How to avoid Hive Staging Area Write on Cloud

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, google-cloud-storage

I have to frequently write Dataframes as Hive tables.

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').format('hive').saveAsTable(f'db.{file_nm}_PT')
```

Or use Spark SQL or Hive SQL to copy one table to another as backup.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE db.tbl_bkp PARTITION (op_cd, rpt_dt)
SELECT * FROM db.tbl;
```

Problem is: Writing to hive_saging_directory takes 25% of the total time, whereas 75% or more time goes in moving the ORC files from staging directory to the final partitioned directory structure.

```
21/11/13 00:51:25 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: New loading path = gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2019-10-24 with partSpec {rpt_dt=2019-10-24}
21/11/13 00:51:56 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: Replacing src:gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2018-02-18/part-00058-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, dest: gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/rpt_dt=2018-02-18/part-00058-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, Status:true
21/11/13 00:51:56 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: New loading path = gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2018-02-18 with partSpec {rpt_dt=2018-02-18}
21/11/13 00:52:31 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: Replacing src:gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2019-01-29/part-00046-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, dest: gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/rpt_dt=2019-01-29/part-00046-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, Status:true
21/11/13 00:52:31 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: New loading path = gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2019-01-29 with partSpec {rpt_dt=2019-01-29}
21/11/13 00:53:09 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: Replacing src:gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2020-08-01/part-00020-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, dest: gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/rpt_dt=2020-08-01/part-00020-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, Status:true
21/11/13 00:53:09 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: New loading path = gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2020-08-01 with partSpec {rpt_dt=2020-08-01}
21/11/13 00:53:46 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: Replacing src:gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2021-07-12/part-00026-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, dest: gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/rpt_dt=2021-07-12/part-00026-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, Status:true
21/11/13 00:53:46 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: New loading path = gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2021-07-12 with partSpec {rpt_dt=2021-07-12}
21/11/13 00:54:17 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: Replacing src:gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2022-01-21/part-00062-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, dest: gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/rpt_dt=2022-01-21/part-00062-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, Status:true
21/11/13 00:54:17 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: New loading path = gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2022-01-21 with partSpec {rpt_dt=2022-01-21}
21/11/13 00:54:49 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: Replacing src:gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2018-01-20/part-00063-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, dest: gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/rpt_dt=2018-01-20/part-00063-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, Status:true
21/11/13 00:54:49 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: New loading path = gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2018-01-20 with partSpec {rpt_dt=2018-01-20}
21/11/13 00:55:22 INFO hive.ql.metadata.Hive: Replacing src:gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/.hive-staging_hive_2021-11-12_23-26-38_441_6664318328991520567-1/-ext-10000/rpt_dt=2019-09-01/part-00037-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, dest: gs://sam_tables/teradata/tbl_bkp/rpt_dt=2019-09-01/part-00037-95ee77f0-4e27-4765-a454-e5009c4f33f3.c000, Status:true
```

This operation is quite fast on actual HDFS but on Google cloud blob this rename is actually copy pasting blobs and is very slow.

I have heard about direct path writes, can you all please suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### (not so) Short answer

It's ... complicated. Very complicated. I wanted to write a short answer but I'd risk being misleading on several points. Instead I'll try to give a very short summary of the very long answer.

- Hive uses staging directories for a good reason: atomicity. You don't want users reading a table while it is being re-written, so instead you write in a staging directory and rename the directory when it's done, [like this](https://tenor.com/view/swap-indiana-jones-harrison-ford-indiana-jones-and-the-last-crusade-substitute-gif-21875110).
- Problem is: Cloud storages are "object storages", not "distributed files systems" like HDFS, and [some operations like folder renaming can be much slower because of that](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/bk_cloud-data-access/content/cloud-fs-slower-commands.html).
- Each cloud has it's own storage implementation, with it's own specificities and downsides, and with time they even propose new variants to overcome some of these downsides (e.g. Azure has 3 different storage variants: Blob Storage, Datalake Storage Gen 1 and Gen 2).
- Therefore, the best solution on one cloud isn't necessarily the best on another cloud.
- The FileSystem API implementation for various cloud storage is part of the Hadoop distribution, which Spark uses. So the solutions available to you will also depend on which version of Hadoop your Spark installation is using.
- **Azure/GCS only**: You could try setting [this option]:(https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/cloud-integration.html#configuring): `spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version 2`.
  It is faster than `v1` **but it also not recommended as it is not atomic and therefore *less safe* in case of partial failures**.
- `v2` is currently the default in Hadoop, but [Spark 3 set it back to `v1` by default](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33019) and there are [some discussion in the Hadoop community](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-7282) to deprecate it and make `v1` the default again.
- There are also some [ongoing development to write better output committers for Azure and GCS](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-7341), based on a similar [output committer done for S3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-7341).

---

- Alternatively, you can try switching to cloud-first formats like Apache Iceberg, Apache Hudi or Delta Lake.
- I am not very familiar with these yet, but a quick look at [Delta Lake's documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html) convinced me that they had to deal with same kind of issues (cloud storages not being real file systems), and depending on which cloud you're on, it may require extra configuration, [especially on GCP where the feature is flagged as experimental](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html).
- **EDIT:** Apache Iceberg does not have this issue as it uses [metadata files to point to the real data files location](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/a-short-introduction-to-apache-iceberg-d34f628b6799). Thanks to this, changes to a table are committed via an atomic change on a single metadata file.
- I am not very familiar with Apache Hudi, and I couldn't find any mention of them dealing with these kind of issues. I'd have to dig further into their design architecture to know for sure.

Now, for the long answer, maybe I should write a blog article... I'll post it here whenever it's done.

Comment: good answer. yes, iceberg addresses this as it only has to write a single file to commit a job; no renames.  That MAPREDUCE-7341 committer is ready for beta testing, if people can it'd be great. This weeks work was some obscure load failures modes of abfs that only surface under heavy load -not even TCP DS benchmarks.
PS: do I know you?

Comment: related feature in Hive on EMR and S3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/68744194/2700344 - direct writes to S3

Comment: @stevel Thanks for the info about Iceberg, I updated my answer in that regard. I don't think we've met, no. Nice to meet you!

Comment: nice. one more thing: GCS dir renames and deletes are nonatomic and O(file) using v2 is no worse than v1 there, and the option  "mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.task.cleanup.enabled" should be set to offload some of that tempt cleanup to the tasks. Azure has own issues with deep/wide tree deletion

Comment: @stevel Thanks for the info. in MAPREDUCE-7341 it is written "Google GCS lacks the atomic directory rename required for v1 correctness; v2 can be used (which doesn't have the job commit performance limitations), but it's not safe." The last words make it rather unclear whether users should use v2 or not. I was assuming they shouldn't.
As for GCS, according to Spark's documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/cloud-integration.html#configuring), GCS dir renames are both safe and O(1), so I'm a little confused...

Comment: looks like a mistake by whoever wrote that doc. which, according to git, was me. it's O(files) and nonatomic. From an email from google devs on nov 2019 " directory rename is not atomic on GCS". given that, you may as well use v2